# LightDM doesn't want to start in test mode

Tags: lightdm

I have a problem where LightDM doesn't start when run in test mode `lightdm --test-mode`.

After I ran the same thing in debug, this was the output:

```
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/log/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.14.2, UID=1000 PID=31996
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-lightdm-webkit-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/gnome/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/upstart/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/xdg-gnome/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Running in user mode
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using Xephyr for X servers
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.01s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading properties from config section SeatDefaults
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.01s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1002 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1001 added
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.02s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Logging to /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1.log
[+0.02s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Writing X server authority to /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+0.03s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Launching X Server
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Launching process 32000: /usr/bin/Xephyr :1 -seat seat0 -auth /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1 -nolisten tcp
[+0.03s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Waiting for ready signal from X server :1
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 32000
[+0.07s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Got signal from X server :1
[+0.07s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Connecting to XServer :1
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'vilsol'
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Not setting XDG_VTNR
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/bin/lightdm-webkit-greeter
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/vilsol
[+0.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Logging to /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1-greeter.log
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Greeter closed communication channel
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Session pid=32012: Terminated with signal 11
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping; failed to start a greeter
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server
[+0.20s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 32000
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Process 32000 exited with return value 0
[+0.21s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: X server stopped
[+0.21s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Removing X server authority /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/run/root/:1
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+0.21s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```

There are no actual errors, but for some reason the greeter says that the greeter didn't start. If I reboot, then LightDM shows up properly, so it must be something to do specifically with the test mode.

Comment: In the output it says there's a log created at /home/vilsol/.cache/lightdm/log/x-1-greeter.log   check that file

Comment: @Serg it is completely empty, already checked that. Also tried to run as root, but as root is not associated with an X session, it can't run it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the archives, as the question is quite old (but a top google result).

If you have a look at $HOME/.cache/lightdm/log/x-0.log you may see other errors like these:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE)
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE)
```

You should use lightdm as the display manager, when you test it with "--test-mode" (this is kind of unintuitive, running something, that one wants to test first...). Maybe you are running gdm3 or another dm?